# "Размотался клубок неумолимых мойр"?

Tags: выбор-слов, мифология

> За этим пронзительным стариковским возгласом невольно рисовалась вся
>   прожитая человеком жизнь. В мгновение ока **размотался клубок
>   неумолимых мойр** к самому началу прошлого столетия – к её рождению.

И - один общий клубок?

[Согласно Гомеру](https://www.grekomania.ru/articles/mythology/150-moires),

> мойрами, прядущими нить человеческой судьбы, были три сестры - Лахесис
>   («дающая жребий» ещё до рождения человека), Клото («прядущая» нить
>   человеческой жизни) и Атропос («неотвратимая», неуклонно приближающая
>   будущее). Представлялись они в образе суровых старух: Лахесис с меркой
>   или весами, Клото с веретеном в руке, Атропос с книгой жизни и
>   ножницами - разрыв нити означал смерть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Священные пряхи в древней Греции назывались Мойры (доля, судьба) . Поскольку судьба – сила темная, невидимая, изображений мойр в античном искусстве почти не встречается. Мойры – дочери первообразующей силы Никты, порождения Хаоса. **Ремесло Мойр было организовано следующим образом:** Клото пряла нить судьбы, сматывая ее в клубок, Лахесис отмеряла нить и разматывала клубочек, пропуская нить жизни через все невзгоды, Антропос, сверяясь с книгой жизни, ножницами обрезала нить: разрыв – смерть.

http://22oa.ru/priakha-iz-moir-5-bukv/

Comment: И... что из этого следует? Где ответ на вопрос - на шапку евойную?